# ELK Stack reading from S3 Bucket

Tags: elk

I am new to the ELK stack and seem to be stuck. I run a website built on Spring Boot and hosted on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I would like to run an ELK stack in my house to aggregate the tomcat application logs as well as nginx access/error logs, but does not expose any ports to the internet.

1. In the configuration for the Elastic Beanstalk Environment under "Updates, monitoring, and logging" checked the box for S3 Log Rotate which copies the logs from the EC2 instance to an S3 bucket.  This happens about once an hour.
2. I then setup notifications on the S3 bucket where the logs are stored to create a message in an SQS Queue any time new file are created.
3. On a computer at my house I setup the ELK stack on Ubuntu and got it all working.
4. On the same computer at my house installed FileBeats and configured it to watch the SQS queue for messages and automatically download the files and process them.

All of this is working and I am getting data flowing into Elastic. However, I seem to be missing something. All of the logs are going into Elastic search as just plain text. They are not being processed. This is the part I confused about. It feels like I need to setup something in logstash to key on the S3 bucket path and filename or something else to tell it to use the nginx parser or the tomcat logs.